# jpa merge Predicate array + search for foreign key value

Tags: jpa

I would like to have a search like this:

```
Select * From Users where ( ( username Like %criteria% OR firstName Like %criteria% ...) AND (CarId = carId) )
```

I did with 2 Predicate combined into an array, but need to do it with 1 Predicate only

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username" }) })
public class User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_id_user", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_id_user", sequenceName = "seq_id_user")
private Long id;
@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String username;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
....
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CAR_ID_FK"))
private Car car;
...
```

The Car is a similar class, the User has 1 foreign key.

```
@Override
public List<User> searchUsers(String criteria, Car car) {
    //TODO: check params and return values based on test cases

    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> r = query.from(User.class);

    Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();

    predicate = builder.or(predicate, builder.like(r.get("username"), "%" + criteria + "%"));
    predicate = builder.or(predicate, builder.like(r.get("firstName"), "%" + criteria + "%"));
    predicate = builder.or(predicate, builder.like(r.get("lastName"), "%" + criteria + "%"));
    predicate = builder.or(predicate, builder.like(r.get("nickname"), "%" + criteria + "%"));

    // how to implement the filter by foreign key value with AND? - can be a sub query to, which will be executed first time
    // I  need to use 1 Predicate, not a Predicate Array!
    query.select(r).where(predicate);

    List<User> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```